# ¿Cómo puedo establecer conexión bluetooth con un arduino que siempre me esta enviando datos de un dispositivo medico?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

Buen dia.

Quiero establecer conexión bluetooth  de un app con una tarjeta arduino. Esta tarjeta envía datos por bluetooth constantemente y cuando quiero emparejar ambos dispositivos la conexion se rechaza.
Este es el codigo de la tarjeta arduino:

```html
#include <eHealth.h>
  float datosECG[200], ImprimeDatosECG[100]; 
  float PosPar;
  int pos,i,cont=0; 
// The setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
//  Serial.println("Datos");
}
// The loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
if(eHealth.getECG()>0.5){
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    pos=i;
    datosECG[i] = eHealth.getECG();
    PosPar = pos%50;
    
    if(PosPar==0){
                    Serial.print('#'); 
                    Serial.println("ecg"); 
        Serial.println(datosECG[i]);
                    Serial.print("\n");
                    Serial.print('~');
                    Serial.print("\n");        
    }
  }
  delay(1); // wait for a millisecond
}
}
```

Sin embargo, me di cuenta que si aumento el delay a por ejemplo 1000ms si puedo establecer conexión. 
El problema es que los datos necesariamente deben ser enviados con un delay de 1 ms.

¿A qué se debe esto? 
¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

No se bien que esta pasando.
Este es el codigo de la clase que lee el flujo  de entrada.

```
  private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final InputStream mmInStream;
private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
private DataParse mDataParse;

public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
    Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
    mmSocket = socket;
    InputStream tmpIn = null;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;

    try {
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
    }

    mmInStream = tmpIn;
    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
}


public void run() {
    Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
    int bytes;
    mDataParse = new DataParse(mHandler);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Mientras se mantenga la conexion el hilo se mantiene en espera ocupada
    // leyendo del flujo de entrada
    while (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
        try {
            // Leemos del flujo de entrada del socket
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            //byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

            mDataParse.Add(buffer, bytes);

            String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                                mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MSG_LEER,bytes,-1,readMessage).sendToTarget();

            //System.out.println("Bytes: "+bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
            connectionLost();
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BluetoothChatService.this.start();
            break;
        }

       /* try {
            Thread.sleep(40);//originalmente estaba en 40
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

    }
}

/**
 * Write to the connected OutStream.
 * @param buffer  The bytes to write
 */
public void write(byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        mmOutStream.write(buffer);

        // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
        mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                            //(Message.what (int),Message.arg1 (int),Message.arg2 (int), Message.obj  (byte[]))
                .sendToTarget();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
    }
}

public void cancel() {
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que comentas y el código que proporcionas, el problema puede deberse a que superas el ancho de banda del puerto serie.

Esto encaja con que no tengas problemas al aumentar el dalay, pues al hacerlo reduces el numero de bits por segundo  que envías.

Lo tienes configurado a 115200 que son bits por segundo, convertido en bytes, vienen a ser 14400 bytes.

Tu quieres enviar datos cada 1ms 14400/1000ms, puedes enviar 14.4 bytes por milisegundo con tu ancho de banda, un caracter ASCII ocupa un byte.

Entonces solo puedes enviar 14.4 caracteres por milisegundo.

Intenta reducir el numero de caracteres que envías, un saludo ^^

Comment: Hola @Ivan G Domenech  gracias por responder.
Si eso fue una las cosas que había pensado, sin embargo, si te das cuenta lo que mando a imprimir son menos de 14 caracteres.
No obstante también hice pruebas mandando únicamente el valor del ecg, y pasa lo mismo, Cheque con otra aplicación de la playstore y me hace lo mismo.
Esto es lo que pasa con la app de la playstore y con la mia: 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OLQp2V8ILsVzFxTk1oX19PYlk

Answer (score 2):

Buen día, después de haber buscado y sin encontrar respuesta alguna lo que decidí hacer fue poner un delay de 1 minuto en el código de inicio de arduino  para que así la aplicacion no enviara nada de datos y al final poder establecer la conexión bluetooth, se que no es lo mas optimo pero al no encontrar respuesta es lo único que se me vino a la mente y que sirvió para mi propósito, espero que a alguien le sirva esto, saludos.